# How to access private static variable in static member function of another class?

Tags: c++

In this situation,

A.h

```
#include "B.h"

class A{
    private:
        static int n;
        friend void B::setN(int _n);
};
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

int A::n = 0;
```

B.h

```
class B{
    public:
        static void setN(int _n);
};
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

void B::setN(int _n) { A::n = _n; }
```

> **IntelliSense: member "A::n" (declared at of "A.h") is inaccessible** has occured.

But if I correct **friend void B::setN(int _n);** to **friend class B;**, it has no error.

Why can't I use this way?

I hope that only the static member function is accessible.

Comment: The code seems to work on GCC 4.7.

Comment: I think that if method setN is public and static, by making it friend with A you would allow public access to private members of A. What happens if you make setN private?

Comment: I worked with VS2013, But yeah, I tested it on GCC now, and it works. I think I'm missing something else.

Comment: @VAndrei I know it is not different private/public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cause **IntelliSense Error** only, not compile error.

Answer (score 0):

missed a semicolon

```
void B::setN(int _n) { A::n = _n; }
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed when i wrote this question.